# why hashCode() comparison is true and just comparison is false for two variables with string values?

Tags: java, hashcode

```
public class a {
public static void main(String args[]){
final String s1="job";
final String s2="seeker";
String s3=s1.concat(s2);
String s4="jobseeker";
System.out.println(s3==s4);=> false
System.out.println(s3.hashCode()==s4.hashCode());=>true
System.out.println(s3.hashCode());=>2201324
System.out.println(s4.hashCode());=>2201324

}
}
```

"==" compare hashCode of the Object... .hashCode of the s3 and s4 are the same but s3==s4 gives false . Anyone explain. I need an answer not useless question not in correct format comments. people who do not know answer keep away from this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [two unequal objects with same hashcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400711/two-unequal-objects-with-same-hashcode)

Comment: It semms you should also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: s3==s4 compares references, s3.equals(s4) compares hashCodes

Comment: YM .equals compares **values** not hashcodes (and not references).

Answer (score 0):

1. Java Strings can't be compared using == operator, because it only compares references. Use s3.equals(s4) for string comparison overload.
2. I guess that `s3.hashCode() == s4.hashCode()` evaluates to true because it compares integers, which are compared by value in Java.

Comment: s3.hashCode() == s4.hashCode() evalutase to true, because hashCode() returns an int, which can be compared with ==

Comment: Right, obviously :) Anyway, ints can be compared with ==, strings not (as long as you're interested in contents, not reference).