# hashCode for classes implementing the same interface

Tags: java

I have (at least) two classes that implement the same interface and have the same fields. Is it ok if those two classes have the same hash code if their fields are identical or should they be different? Is this code ok?

```
interface Base { }

class A implements Base {
  private Integer value;

  public A(Integer value) { this.value = value; }

  public int hashCode() { return value.hashCode(); }
}

class B implements Base {
  private Integer value;

  public B(Integer value) { this.value = value; }

  public int hashCode() { return value.hashCode(); }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have two classes of it?

Comment: It is fine for them to have similar `hashCode` implementations if it makes sense for both of them. Though from your question it's somewhat unclear what the purpose of these two classes is.

Comment: The only requirement for `hashCode` is that `A.equals(B) ==> A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()`. Also: you should always modify both `hashCode` and `equals` together to keep that requirement... Obviously doing this will have implications. For example Python does this with numbers classes so that integer `1` is equal to float `1.0`, but this implies that if you have a map like `{1: "a"}` then you can use `1.0` in place of `1` to fetch that value and you cannot have both `1` and `1.0` as keys since they are effectively identical for the hashmap

Comment: I'd say, it's certainly not a problem. Worst thing that could happen: A few more hash collisions in a `Map` or `Set` containing instances of both classes. But you could also just add the hashcode of the class itself to the instances' hashcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to have the same hashcode for different objects. 
As you know hashcodes range restricted by `int` type in java. But the range of objects is not restricted. The situation where different objects have the same hashcode called ***collision***.
 
To avoid errors related to it you should remember about the contract between hashcode and equals:
1) If two objects are **equal**, then they **must have the same hash code**.
2) If two objects **have the same hash code**, they **may or may not be equal**.
You can find more about it [here](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/)

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a similar situation. Basically, the implementations (I had two) would look exactly alike.

If I had used just one class then the class name created confusion when used at the other place. So, I went ahead with two classes to improve readability.

Example: Hooks that are used `pre` and `post` initialization of something lead to creating two classes `PreInit` and `PostInit`. But, at that time, the requirement was to do the *same thing* at the pre and post init. But, in the very near future, this would change and each will have different logic.

Two different objects can have the same hash code and there is nothing wrong about that (as long as you take care of the `equals`)

See:
[two unequal objects with same hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400711/two-unequal-objects-with-same-hashcode/16400762)

Comment: I have no idea why all these downvotes showed up on all answers. Anyway, you got mine up now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Different objects giving the same `hashCode()` is for sure "okay". It is the *nature* of hashes to sometimes collide. A hash code maps a potentially infinite range onto a restricted range. Collisions are inevitable. Especially when thinking about objects of different types, it really doesn't matter too much whether `someA` and `someB` have equal or different hash codes!

But beyond that, the other answer is: your question implies a design problem. You shouldn't ask "is it ok for two interfaces to use the exact hash code". You should rather ask: "why did I end up with with two classes that share so much common aspects?!"

The *real* issue here is code quality: you duplicated fields, and probably code dealing with those fields. Most likely, the "better" approach would be refactor both classes, and push the *common* aspects into a distinct class, and then have your two classes *use* that common class!