# Java String objects equality and reference

Tags: java, string, oop, object

I have the following code:

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String x = "a";
        String y = "a";

        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(x) == System.identityHashCode(y)); //true
        System.out.println(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()); //true

        y = y+"b";

        System.out.println(x); // "a"
        System.out.println(y); // "ab"

        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(x) == System.identityHashCode(y)); //false
        System.out.println(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()); //false
     }
}
```

First I create 2 Strings x and y. Then I check their HashCodes and they are same so it means they are one object and they point to one memory location. But when I change y value, The value of x won't change. If I check their hashcode again, They are different so that means 2 different objects and 2 different memory locations. Why does that happen? Why doesn't x  change when y changes? (because we are just changing the content of one memory)

I used hashcode as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-h) question suggests.

**Update:**
 My confusion was for 2 reasons:

a) I thought same hashcodes mean same objects (You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731916/12828249) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16400762/12828249) questions for the detailed explanation why I'm wrong.)

b) Strings are immutable and if the value changes, New Strings are created (As explained in the answers below.)

Comment: look  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Comment: Having equal hashcodes do *not* mean the objects are the same!  Hashcode is an int so here are only 4 billion possible hashcodes, but there are many more possible strings, so there must be collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Java are immutable. You aren't "changing the value of y", you're creating a new string and assigning it to y. Since you haven't assigned anything else to x, it will still reference the previous string you had there.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question ultimately stems from your misunderstanding that `x` and `y` are objects. **`x` and `y` are not objects.**

`x` and `y` are *variables* and since `String` is a reference type, `x` and `y` store *references* to objects. The `=` assignment operator changes what reference these variables store.

In these two lines:

```
String x = "a";
String y = "a";
```

`x` and `y` store references that refers to the same object.

But when you do `y = y + "b"`, the `y + "b"` creates a *new object*. Then the `=` make `y` store a reference to that new object, so `y` no longer points to the same object as `x`.